# Python: CX_Freeze issue after build

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I created a small converter and after building it with CX_Freeze it shows this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\users\LDC\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36-32\lib\sitr\e-packages\cx_freeze\initscripts_startup_.py", line14 in run module.run()
File "C:\users\LDC\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36-32\lib\sitr\e-packages\cx_freeze\initscripts\console.py", line26 in run exec(code,m.*dict*)
File"GUI1.py",line 1, in 
File
"C:\USERS\LDC\APPDATA\LOCAL\PROGRAMS\PYTHON\PYTHON36-32\LIB\TKINTER_INIT_.PY",line36,in 
import_tkinter#If this fails your python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found

[This is a screen shot from the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O0u1.png)

Now this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window1=Tk()

def convert():
    var2=var1.get()
    var3=var2*3.785
    e2.insert(0,var3)

def clear():
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)

def quit():
    window1.destroy()

var1=IntVar()
label1=Label(window1,text='Gallons',padx=25).grid(row=0,sticky=W)
e1=Entry(window1,width=25,textvariable=var1)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
label2=Label(window1,text='Liters',padx=25).grid(row=1,sticky=W)
e2=Entry(window1,width=25)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)

window1.title("Converter")
window1.geometry("400x200+200+200")
button1= Button(text='convert',command=convert,width=15,).grid(row=4,column=0)
button2= Button(text='clear',command=clear,width=15).grid(row=4,column=1)
button3= Button(text='exit',command=quit,width=15).grid(row=5,column=1)

mymenu=Menu()
mymenu.add_cascade(label='File')
mymenu.add_cascade(label='Edit')
mymenu.add_cascade(label='View')
mymenu.add_cascade(label='Tools')
mymenu.add_cascade(label='Help')
window1.config(menu=mymenu)

window1.mainloop()
```

and this is the setup code

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("GUI1.py", base=base, icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "GUI1",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":["clienticon.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Ya Rb",
    executables = executables
    )
```

I tried the following with no luck:
1. uninstalled cx freeze and installed it again
2. tried different version of python .. python 2.7
3. tried to use py2exe and pyinstaller got different errors
4. also made sure that the python path in the environment is set correctly

Thanks in advance appreciate your help..

Comment: Are you running the latest version of cx_Freeze?  5.1 or somthing because if not update it.

Comment: yes cx_freeze 5.1.1 and python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not as bad as it looks.  You just need to know the path to your Python installation.

What the error means:  you've included the tkinter library but forgotten the tkinter run-times (tk86t.dll and tcl86t.dll).  For your script to work you need to include them.

This can be done with the use of `include_files` statement.  A quick search through the installation reveals they are located in a folder called `DLLs`.  We need to give the file path and the file names we want to the setup script.  This can be done like this:

```
  "include_files":["<path to python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll","<path to python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"]
```

and it will now work.

Your setup script will look like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("GUI1.py", base=base, icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "GUI1",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":["clienticon.ico", "<path to python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll","<path to python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Ya Rb",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: @AhmedEssam I'm so pleased. Very happy I could help, I really enjoy helping don't hesitate to ask if you have further cx_freeze problems and I'll see what I can do.